# How do i change the Navbar Position when Bootstrap goes responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

The desktop view of the website got a logo and a navigation under it.
I want the position of the navigation to become above the logo (and also create a little space between the logo and navbar) when it switches to mobile view.

Here is desktop view:

[image: desktop]

Mobile view:

[image: mobile]

What I want mobile view to **be**:

[image: how I want mobile]

---

HTML:

```
    <div class="text-center logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/brand.png" /></a>
        <span class="brand-headline visible-desktop">
            <p class="title-text">Example</p>
        </span>
    </div>

<!-- =begin navigation !-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-target">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <span class="navbar-brand brand" href="#">Brand</span>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-target">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Schuhe</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Code, please. The moose out front shoulda told ya.

Comment: Kinda clueless what to post. Only HTML structure ?

Comment: HTML and any relevant or Bootstrap-override CSS.

Comment: Just added the HTML structure. CSS is pretty much without any bootstrap overriding commands. I am just not sure to use @media . Just want to change the navigation to a fixed top when it's getting responsive.

Comment: Look up the @media queries. This is specifically what they are designed to do.

Comment: Try to make a jSBin / CodePen / Bootply in future. You'll get a lot more help that way.

Comment: I posted my answer using a small script, try it out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until there's more support for FlexBox the way I do it is to clone it with jQuery. I do it all the time since BS3 menu requires jQuery anyway.

**THE DEMO:**
http://jsbin.com/oVifowe/1/

```
/* __________________ Mobile Menu __________________*/
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('.navbar').clone().removeClass('hidden-xs').appendTo('.mobile-menu');

 }); //end
```

The HTML:

```
 <div class="mobile-menu visible-xs"><!--MENU CLONES HERE--></div>

 <div class="text-center logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/brand.png" /></a>
    <span class="brand-headline visible-desktop">
        <p class="title-text">LOGO</p>
    </span>
</div>

<!-- begin navigation !-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-xs" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-target">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-target">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Schuhe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default {
     position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:1030;
   }
}
```

You may also want to add top padding to body or main wrapper on tablets and smaller.

Answer (score 1):

you can make the position of the navigation fixed top on small devices. Other than that, you may have to switch templates for the different versions because you are changing the order of the html flow.

Comment: Yes. The order of the content on mobile is the order of the content on desktop. You can manipulate the desktop view with position absolute, floats, heights and stuff to make it look like the nav is below the header. That would be done in min-widths

Comment: Bart means when you make some block fixed it's removed from main flow and placed in a separate one. This may lead to some inconvenience, you may have to add some paddings for a main wrapper/body and stuff.

Comment: he have A B C on desktop and B A C on mobile. in case you didn't noticed.